# In Scala, when is it necessary to specify laziness?

Tags: scala, lazy-evaluation

In the local Scala REPL, one can define streams and lazy lists without the keyword `lazy`.

```
scala> val fibo: LazyList[BigInt] = (0: BigInt) #:: (1: BigInt) #:: fibo.zip(fibo.tail).map { n => n._1 + n._2 }
fibo: LazyList[BigInt] = LazyList(<not computed>)

scala> fibo(100)
res17: BigInt = 354224848179261915075

scala> val prime: LazyList[Int] = 2 #:: LazyList.from(3).filter(i => prime.takeWhile {
     |    j => j * j <= i
     | }.forall {
     |    k => i % k != 0
     | })
prime: LazyList[Int] = LazyList(<not computed>)

scala> prime(100)
res18: Int = 547
```

This would work much the same way with `Stream`, and also in Scastie. It should also work in an IntelliJ project, right?

```
  @Test def testGCDConsecutivePrimeNumbers(): Unit = {
    val prime: LazyList[Int] = 2 #:: LazyList.from(3).filter(i => prime.takeWhile {
      j => j * j <= i
    }.forall {
      k => i % k != 0
    })
    for (n <- 1 to 100) {
      assertEquals(1, gcd(prime(n), prime(n + 1)))
    }
  }

  @Test def testGCDConsecutiveEvenFibonacciNumbers(): Unit = {
    val fibo: LazyList[Int] = 0 #:: 1 #:: fibo.zip(fibo.tail).map(n => n._1 + n._2)
    for (i <- 0 to 42 by 3) {
      assertEquals(2, gcd(fibo(i), fibo(i + 3)))
    }
  }
```

Except it doesn't.

> Error:(21, 67) forward reference extends over definition of value `prime`
>
> `val prime: LazyList[Int] = 2 #:: LazyList.from(3).filter(i => prime.takeWhile {`
>
> Error:(32, 43) forward reference extends over definition of value `fibo`
>
> `val fibo: LazyList[Int] = 0 #:: 1 #:: fibo.zip(fibo.tail).map(n => n._1 + n._2)`

Marking them lazy clears the errors.

I understand some things work differently in the REPL, but I don't understand why this would be one of those things. And I'm probably missing some subtlety here, but why doesn't omitting "`lazy`" in the REPL cause a forward reference error. In general, when is it necessary to explicitly specify laziness, and why?

Answer (score 5):

It isn't directly "one of those things" which "work differently in the REPL", but it is because of them. In the failing code, `prime` and `fibo` are local variables. When you define them directly in the REPL they are properties of an anonymous object, i.e. it generates something like

```
object Line1 {
  val fibo = ...
}
import Line1.fibo
```

And if you look at the specification, [the forward reference restriction](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html) only applies to local variables:

> It can form part of an object or class definition or it can be local to a block...
>
> However, there is a restriction on forward references **in blocks**